# How is the bottom resistor fed?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current

To make this simple, I have two questions:

1. Does the left-most voltage generator's current flow through the right-most voltage generator, or does it stop once it meets another different current?
2. Do they clash so the higher one takes over or what is the behavior of current there?

[image]

Comment: What does Kirchoff's current law tell you?

Comment: @Finbarr it requires a knot first i dont see knots in that circuit, but neverthless then i_1 =-  i_2

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI No knots needed. KCL always applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *does the left-most voltage generator's current flow through the
> right-most voltage generator*

It's a single loop and, no matter how many two-terminal devices (components or sources) are in series, the current flow through all devices is identical. This also answers your 2nd question.

Comment: so the same current flows across -and pierces in a sense- the generators?

Comment: Current flows exclusively in the loop and, is the same current at every point in the loop.

Comment: so \$8 = 10000i + 4V_1 + 12 - V_1\$ also is the voltage-source in series or in parallel?

Comment: Yes that looks about right. All components and devices are in series.